# I need some MySQL lookup table advice

Tags: mysql, php, database

I have a MySQL database with about 200 tables. 50 of these are small 2-field 'id-data' lookup tables. Several of these DB's are hosted on a shared server. I have been informed that I need to reduce the total number of tables in the shared hosting environment because of performance issues relating to too many tables.

My question is: Could/Should the 50 2-Field lookup tables be combined into a single 3-field table with 'id-field_name-data' Fields? Even if this can be done, I will have a lot of work to do on the PHP user application. My other choice is moving the DB's to a dedicated server at much higher hosting cost.

I don't believe my 200 table DB's are actually causing any performance issues on this shared hosting server, at least not from the user application standpoint. There are never more than 10 of these tables joined in any single query; although I have seen some very-slow queries generated by phpmyadmin on these DB's.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the 'id-field-data' approach given the following conditions:

1- Your tables don't contain too many records. So, the final table will NOT be too huge.

2- Creating an index on the `field` field to make the search faster.

3- Modifying your PHP code is not difficult and you can do it in a manageable way to avoid breaking it.

4- Creating another copy of your code/tables and when done you can remove the unneeded tables/code.